# How to exclude the /command from message_handler in the dispatcher of Aiogram?

Tags: python, python-3.x, command, telegram, telegram-bot

I've a message handler that respond to a command in a Bot application written in python3 with the library Aiogram.

I can receive from the application the message I send to the BOT, but I would like to exclude the command (via config possibly, not parsing the string). Maybe it is in the documentation, but currently I could not find the answer.

To be clear with an example, if I type to my TelegramBot

```
/my_command text
```

where this is my code in the python3 application

```
@dispatcher.message_handler(commands=['my_command'])
async def echo(message: types.Message):
```

I would like to receive from the message_handler in the `message types.Message` variable the string `text` and not `/my_command text`.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The function to extract only the arguments of a command is `get_args()`:

```
@dispatcher.message_handler(commands=['my_command'])
async def echo(message: types.Message):
    arguments = message.get_args()
    await message.reply(arguments)
```